# how to apply .active class to only one menu item that uses optional filters

Tags: routes, views

I have an exposed a filter to a page like so in drupal: http:example.com/user?profile=12 There is a menu entry for this specific link in a block in the sidebar. Is there a way drupal can add the .active class to the link with this specific url. Currently the active class is applied to links with this pattern: http://example.com/user?profile*

Which happen to be all links in that block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A page with optional filters set in the url is not treated as a new different page, hence the .active class is applied on all pages with the same pattern. Use of a contextual filter such that the path changes to something like:

> http://example.com/user/1

will fix this problem, since each new url will be pointing to a new page.